# #REF! error in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, ref

I have a spread sheet which can be viewed at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bhIV1ULLXhjdSO_5Q5l5ZNe7Zaxrj15CYMW88FMFgRU/edit?usp=sharing

The way the spread sheet works is when a selection from the list is made the specific cells reference a data table and fills in the respective cells. This works perfectly in excel and I just use Iferror to hide the circular references. This is not the case in google sheets as the #REF! error still appears. How can I rectify so that they no longer appear? I have tried unique but it makes all the cells bank even when a different selection from the drop down box is made.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ISREF()` function for this. Combine it with an `IF()` and you're good to go:

`IF(ISREF('sheetname'!A4), 'sheetname'!A4, "")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the formula itself is fine but (for column N) `'Attributes-InSeason-Trade_Mach'!$L121` and the following rows evaluate to `""`.

This means for `INDEX` in Google Spreadsheets that it will use *all* rows which in turn would overwrite the data in the next row because `INDEX` will be returning a range, not a single cell.
The Formula itself is evaluating fine, it does not cause an error which is why `IFERROR` does not trigger the alterantive `""`, the problem happens after the evaluation when it is trying to display the data.

You can just wrap the `INDEX` Call inside of an `IF` like this (This is an example for Column N)

```
=IFERROR(IF('Attributes-InSeason-Trade_Mach'!$L110 <> "", 
            INDEX('Attributes-InSeason-Trade_Mach'!$H$110:$I$214,
                  'Attributes-InSeason-Trade_Mach'!$L110,
                   COLUMNS(Trade_Machine!$P$4:P4)), ""), "")
```